# VBA - PowerPivot - Table names

Tags: vba, powerpivot

**How to get the list of tables (tabs) in a PowerPivot file in VBA?**

Comment: Can you provide more details? Each of your pivot table is in a Sheet, is that what you called as tabs, like Sheet tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Ganesh,

If we are talking about PowerPivot in Excel 2010 then I would say that its going to be tough although not totally impossible.

The problem is that this version of PowerPivot isn't formally controllable by VBA but that doesn't mean it can't be done. Check out Tom's blog [here](http://blog.gobansaor.com/) as he's pretty much the only guy I know out there thats really got a handle on this.

Other question is what is your end goal? Presuming that getting this via VBA is purely a means to achieving something else.

Jacob